# $A(I-BB^T)C^T$ in Einstein notation

Tags: matrices

I'm a bit confused by using Einstein summation over more than two matrices being multiplied together. I want to write $CD^T=A(I-BB^T)C^T$ in Einstein summation notation, where $D^T$ is the transpose of the matrix $D$. How do I write the indices that we're summing over?

Comment: I don't understand the question. You have two matrices -- one on the left and one on the right. The left would be $(CD^T)_{ij} = C_{ik}D_{jk}$.

Comment: Yes so I need to write CD^T in Einstein summation, but I thought that it would be c_ij d_ji  Then I need to write A(I-BB^T)C^T in Einstein summation notation but I am unsure of how to write this.

Comment: No. $C_{ij}D_{ji}$ is $(CD)_{ii}$.

Comment: OK thanks, and do you know how to write the second part?

Comment: Sure. You can start writing it as $AC^T-ABB^TC^T$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In Einstein's summation notation,
$$\begin{align} 
(CD^T)_{ij} &= C_{ia}(D^T)_{aj} = C_{ia}D_{ja}\\
(A(I-BB^T)C^T)_{ij}
&= A_{ia}(I - BB^T)_{ab}(C^T)_{bj}\\
&= A_{ia}(\delta_{ab} - (BB^T)_{ab})C_{jb}\\
&= A_{ia}(\delta_{ab} - B_{ac}(B^T)_{cb})C_{jb}\\
&= A_{ia}(\delta_{ab} - B_{ac} B_{bc})C_{jb}
\end{align}
$$
where $\delta_{ab}$ is the [Kronecker delta](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kronecker_delta).

The equality $CD^T=A(I−BB^T)C^T$ becomes

$$C_{ia}D_{ja} = A_{ia}(\delta_{ab} - B_{ac} B_{bc})C_{jb}
= A_{ia}C_{ja} - A_{ia}B_{ac}B_{bc}C_{jb}
$$